# Node JS and making external web calls successfully?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services

Hi I am trying to start learning NodeJS now and am in the middle of creating an application. The goal currently is to call a website through node, get an authentication token, then call that website again now with a POST payload which includes my login info and the auth token.
I have created the same program using python and i get a 200 response where in nodeJS i am getting a 302.

I believe thats a quick solution, the main meat of the problem I guess is my lack of understanding in NodeJS where:
1. If I am supposed to nest these requests calls into one another because they are supposed to be a part of the same 'session' and 
2. If so how do I go to the last url which is, example.com/poll and be able to store/modify that information (which is just a json) because/if i go to example.com/poll url using a browser, the browser automatically downloads a file which it contains is a JSON format and doesnt just display it, which is what i need. so that i can either save that data in a string or etc. and not download it

In python I do this (Create a session than make the two calls)

```
url = "https://example.com/"
session = requests.session()
first_req = session.get(url)
auth_token_str = re.search(XXX, first_req.text)
login_url = 'https://example.com/sessions'
payload = { 'session[username_or_email]' : 'username', 'session[password]' : 'password', 'redirect_after_login':'/', 'authenticity_token': authenticity_token }
login_req = session.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=user_agent)
print "login_req response: ", login_req.status_code //gets me 200
```

then in Node JS:

```
var initLoad = {
method: 'GET',
url: 'https://example.com/',
headers: {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36'
  }
};
request(initLoad, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var $ = cheerio.load(body, {xmlMode: false});
  var authenticityToken = $("input[name=authenticity_token]").val();
  console.log(authenticityToken);
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/sessions',
    headers: response.headers,
    form: {
      'session[username_or_email]': 'someUsername',
      'session[password]': 'somePassword',
      redirect_after_login: '/',
      authenticity_token: authenticityToken
    }
  };
  request(options, function(error, response2, body2) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response2.statusCode); //gets me 302 not 200
    var analytics_url = 'https://example.com/poll';
    var tripleload = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: analytics_url,
      headers: response2.headers
    };
    request(tripleload, function(error, response3, body3) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      res.end(body3);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you probably need to specify `jar`, look at the 6th section in the `request` docs [here](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

Comment: Looks like the request module does not follow redirects for non-Get methods (by default). Since you are doing a POST I would try adding `followAllRedirects: true` in the options before calling the POST where you are getting the 302. Another thing I would try is see where you are being redirected to and try that url for the POST

Comment: I tried adding the followAllRedirects into my options before calling the post and had no resolve. The interesting thing the body says: "You are being redirected to example.com/login/error?username_or_email=username&redirect_afteR_login=/" meaning that for some reason the info does not work when i send it over through NodeJS but I am doing the complete exact same thing in Python which is confusing me @AndrewLohr

Answer (score 0):

302 means temporarily moved redirection which you get due error page being displayed to you (or served to your server in this case). There is something with this call that you are doing wrong, maybe url is wrong if generated like this.

Your code is messy due you being newbie in node and due the fact you use request which is barebone and offers little to no comfort in writing this stuff.

Use something like Axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios to make it easier to write requests like this.